# DoDirectPayment with Paypal and Discover Card

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

I have set up my site to accept **Credit Card payments with Paypal**, and I am using **DoDirectPayment** method for the same.

For **Sandbox card** details, the transaction runs successfully, without any problems for any type of cards.

But for **Live card** details, Paypal does not accept payments from American Express and Discover Card.
I researched few links, and found out that, there has to be special card acceptance procedure between paypal and American express cards(please refer the image).
[image]

I wanted to know if there is anything similar
 to be done for Discover cards.
I get this message when i try to make a payment from a Discover card: ***"The card you entered cannot be used for this payment. Please enter a different credit or debit card number."***

Any help is greatly appreciated.
If I am missing any specifics/anycode/any api names please do ask.

Comment: I'm not aware of any Discover-specific agreement (although I can't give an authoritative answer). However, that same message can happen when a card fails some other fraud or risk check. It's intentionally fairly generic. I would suspect that somewhere along the chain (PayPal or Discover or your issuing bank if that isn't Discover) someone has declined the transaction.